# Dynamics 365 for Government - Authentication Methods

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-gov, egovernment

Is there any standards for authenticating with Dynamics 365 CRM for Government ? Is it same for Dynamics 365 CRM commercial instance ?

Comment: At least I am not aware of such special authentication methods from Dynamics 365. But maybe some one with more knowledge could add more info here.

Answer (score 0):

There is only AAD (Azure Active directory) which is being used for authentication part of Dynamics 365 (CRM online) and Single Sign On, then you can enable Multi-factor authentication using Azure Authenticator/Duo providers.

If you are in Government cloud, then all your offerings will be governed by that tenant.